# How to transform the hex signature into a binary signature prior to verification

Tags: hex, sha256, xxd

I need signature data in hex form, so I use:

`openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign ./id_rsa my.data > my.signature`

The openssl docs note that:

> Hex signatures cannot be verified using openssl. Instead, use "xxd -r" or similar program to transform the hex signature into a binary signature prior to verification. [Source](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Dgst(1)#NOTES)

But, when I try to do this ...

`echo "$(cat my.signature)" | xxd -r -p > binary.signature`

... I get nothing

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Dan, the hex signature file is not a plain hex string. It starts with non-hex prefix that `xxd` failes to parse. Something like `RSA-SHA256(my.data)=`. You need to remove it before verification.

```
cat my.signature | sed -e 's/.*= \([^ ]\+\)$/\1/' | xxd -r -p > binary.signature
```

One little tip. If you used `ssh-keygen` to create file `id_rsa`, then corresponding `id_rsa.pub` is not suitable for `openssl`, it is in ssh format. You need to generate a public key in PEM format.

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout > id_rsa.pub.pem
```

This is the right format for verification.

```
openssl dgst -verify id_rsa.pub.pem -signature binary.signature my.data
-> Verified OK
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight -- that sed syntax doesn't seem to work, unfortunately

Comment: Update: apparently it's due to differences between linux sed and macOS sed

Comment: I'm a perfect dummy in MacOS )
Though I tried those snippets in Linux and they worked. 
The idea in sed regex is to find the trailing sequence without spaces.